# Bootstrap Juju controller onto Openstack cloud

Tags: juju, openstack

I am trying to bootstrap Juju controller onto OpenStack cloud using command `juju bootstrap cloud_name controller-name`
but it's failing  with the below error

[image]

In the OS cloud, we don't have `cinder`. Not sure if it'ss failing because of that. Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

After some research was able to figure out why it was failing. Juju doesn't have any information about the image which needs to be used to create the controller VM in OpenStack. Hence the need to generate the meta data for that.

```
juju metadata generate-image -d ~/simplestreams -i $IMAGE_ID -s $OS_SERIES -r $REGION -u http://$KEYSTONE_IP:5000/v2.0/
```

`IMAGE_ID` should be the ID of the Ubuntu image stored in Glance. OS_SERIES is the release name.

After the metadata is created, it needs to source it during the bootstrapping process.

```
juju bootstrap --metadata-source /root/simplestreams
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as i do not have enough credits, but the comment/question is what version of juju are you using ? because i cannot get "metadata" command to work. See [unrecognized command: juju metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898585/unrecognized-command-juju-metadata).

Thanks

Comment: I've used --metadata-source command with juju 2.2. Not sure for previous versions